# what does a dependent row means geometrically in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

for example given a 3x3 matrix 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we can see that the 3rd column vector is dependent 
 so their span is a plane 
 but is 3rd row is also dependent as it is 
2 times row 2 minus row 1 
so what does that means geometrically  ?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand your question, but I have a guess. Could you confirm this for me? I think you are interpreting the matrix as a linear transformation, and you are comfortable with the linear dependence of the columns translating into the range of the transformation being a plane, but you're wondering if there's a similar, corresponding interpretation based on the linear dependence in the rows?

Comment: yes i was wondering just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that also the row space is a subspace with dimension $2$, i.e. a plane in this case, or more in general of dimension $r=\operatorname{rank} (A)=\operatorname{rank} (A^T)$.

Comment: so the vector span a plane in 2 dimensions with reference to the original grid.     lets assume that the rows were independent so now the vectors span a plane but in 3 dimension with reference to the original grip

Comment: @ozzyozbourne For a 3-by-3 matrix if the rows (and columns) are linearly independent they span all $R^3$.